# <ion-side-menu> toggleable and opened by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two `<ion-side-menu>` ([documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenu/)) :

`<ion-side-menu side="left">` and `<ion-side-menu side="right">`

I toggle the left one by - `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft()` ([documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/))

and I want it to be opened on load , the only way I found for that is by  -

```
$timeout(function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(true);
});
```

which is work but it cause to a slightly delay and animation of the `<ion-side-menu>`'s on their rendering .

Have you any elegant way for that ?

Example (opened on load):

[image]

Comment: A small improvement could be executing the code in the onEnter method when setting up states for ui-router.

Comment: You want the left side menu to be open on load, do you still want the user to be able to toggle it so it opens and closes after load?

Comment: Yeap , still it should be toggle-able

Comment: my suggestion may be no good then but i was going to tell you to use the `expose-aside-when` directive because that opens it instantly on load without the animation, but I think it makes it no longer toggle-able (unsure though so maybe you could look into this)

Comment: `expose-aside-when` can take in a width media query e.g. `expose-aside-when="(min-width:768px)"` so if you want it that way on one screen size and not another you can control it